# Multiple connections view in Hawtio

Tags: hawtio

Is there a way where in I can view multiple connection information in the same tab in Hawtio? Right now, for every connection, it opens in a new tab. 
I want to view all connections in the same tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hawtio only views a single JVM.

Comment: Thank you Claus :)